# Adding a vertical line to a time series plot

Tags: r

Is is possible to use abline() and add a vertical line to a plot where the x axis contains dates? I've tried many possible date formatting but can't get it to work.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the easiest way is to provide a `Date` object to `abline`:

```
x <- as.Date("2013-05-27")+0:99
y <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
plot(x,y)
abline(v=as.Date("2013-08-01"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The x-axis on a time series plot (plot.ts with ts object) is in decimal form. For example Quarter 2, 2016 on the axis would be 2016.25

There is a package "lubridate" that has a function (decimal_date()) that converts POSIXct and Date dates to the decimal form which are accepted by abline(). So I take the date I want to put a vertical line at on the plot and put it in Date form. Then I can put that into the decimal_date function and into abline

```r
install.packages("lubridate")

library(lubridate)

[YOUR PLOT CODE]

date1 <- ymd("2013-08-01")

abline(v=decimal_date(date1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to James' answer there are different [date/time formats](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/time.html) in R. Sometimes dates are stored in the POSIX format and when you plot them `abline` with `as.Date` does not work.

In this case you must use

```
abline(v = as.POSIXct("2013-08-01"))
```

Answer (score 0):

as you can see above, in the answer from jrat14, it works with decimal.
Thus, will also work if you inform the decimal, like this:

```
abline(v=2013.581, col="blue", lty=3)
```

Note, the two parameters to the right are optional as you noted